# Attempting to redefine \dv and \pdv from Physics package to display style without setting the surrounding environment to display style

Tags: displaystyle, physics

I am using the [physics package](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf) which adds the \derivative and \partialderivative commands, in addition to the \dv and \pdv commands which are just the shorthand versions. For those unfamiliar, these commands have a variable number of parameters which makes them even more useful.

```
\( 
    \dv{x} \\ 
    \dv{f}{t}  \\ 
    \dv[2]{h}{x}
\)
```

[image]

These commands default to text style mode, but I am trying to alter the \dv and \pdv commands to default to display style.

This is what I tried.

```
\renewcommand{\pdv}{
    \ensuremath{\displaystyle \partialderivative}
}
\renewcommand{\dv}{
    \ensuremath{\displaystyle \derivative}
}
```

This almost works but it sets the rest of the line to be in display-style mode. I would like if this command does not alter the style of the text around it.

For example,

```
\(
    \dv{f} \qquad \frac{A}{b}
\)
```

Will produce this output:

[image: Current Undesired Output]

But I want it to produce this output:

[image: Desired Output]

I haven't found a way to put the command in its own block while maintaining the ability to pass the variable number of parameters to \derivative and \partialderivative.

Comment: I've posted an answer to the question, but I think that the requested output appearance is _very_ odd: typically you'd expect to apply `\displaystyle` to an entire equation, or at least to all fractions.

Answer (score 3):

The place part of an equation in display style, we need to group it using `{...}`. To do that and allow access to all of the arguments of `\derivative`, we need to grab the arguments using `\dv`. Loading `physics` and using `\ShowCommand\derivative` gives us the information

```latex
> \derivative=document command:
  #1:s
  #2:o
  #3:m
  #4:g
  #5:d()
```

Grabbing the arguments is easy enough, but the rather awkward form means that passing to `\derivative` is non-trivial. Rather than use a complex set of branches, I'd go with `\expanded`:

```latex
\RenewDocumentCommand\dv{somgd()}{%
  {%
    \displaystyle
    \expanded{%
      \derivative
        \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}%
        \IfNoValueF{#2}{[{\unexpanded{#2}}]}%
        {\unexpanded{#3}}%
        \IfNoValueF{#4}{{\unexpanded{#4}}}%
        \IfNoValueF{#5}{({\unexpanded{#5}})}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

The idea here is that other than the mandatory `#3`, we do a test for the existence of each other argument and recreate the correct form using a conditional. As `\derivative` will not expand in `\expanded` but the conditionals will, the net result is `\derivative` followed by the arguments to pass, all set up inside `{\displaystyle ...}`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a very weird thing to want, but `\dv` has a `*` form to switch between two styles of fraction so you can use the `*` and locally subvert `\flatfrac` to use `\dfrac`  just once.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}
\let\savedfrac\flatfrac

\renewcommand{\dv}{%%%
 \def\flatfrac{\let\flatfrac\savedfrac\dfrac}\derivative*%%%
}
\begin{document}

\(
    \dv{f} \qquad \frac{A}{b}
\)

\end{document}
```